# Using "this" keyword inside nested static class java

Tags: java, static, static-class

I have a class say `A`, and a static nested class say `B`.

```
public class A {
    public static class B {
        B(Temp x) {
            x.reg(this); // need to pass the nested class reference.
        }
    }
}
```

Is the above code correct? Can we use `this` keyword inside nested static class constructor?

Please help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try compiling it?

Comment: @Christian I just wanted to know,is this correct way of passing the reference?.

Comment: What do you want `this` to refer to? An A or B? Yes you can use `this` in an inner/nested class same as any other.

Comment: @Radiodef i want to refer to B using "this".

Comment: Then yes you can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, it is. For the runtime, inner classes are just another, separate class. If the inner class is not static it will just have a reference to the outer class, but in your case it's static so not even, so it is exactly as if you created a new class in a new file

Just make sure that you write "public", not "Public"

Answer (score 2):

1) Nested static class doesn’t need reference of Outer class, but Non-static nested class or Inner class requires Outer class reference.

2) Inner class(or non-static nested class) can access both static and non-static members of Outer class. A static class cannot access non-static members of the Outer class. It can access only static members of Outer class.

3) An instance of Inner class cannot be created without an instance of outer class and an Inner class can reference data and methods defined in Outer class in which it nests, so we don’t need to pass reference of an object to the constructor of the Inner class. For this reason Inner classes can make program simple and concise.

for More information please refer this http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-class-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the static class in just like a `static` method. This class belongs to the class but not the instance. Hence, `this` has no meaning in the static context.